# OpenCV - std::length_error while training FaceRecognizer

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to use an `LBPHFaceRecognizer`, but I keep getting a length_error exception while calling the `train` method.

The code looks like this:

```
vector<cv::Mat> images;
vector<int> labels;

cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> model = cv::createLBPHFaceRecognizer();

while(getline(galleryFile, line))
{
    folder = line.substr(0, line.find(" "));
    imageNumber = line.substr(line.find(" ") + 1, 4);

    string path = folder;
    path.append("/");
    path.append(imageNumber);
    path.append(".jpg");

    images.push_back(cv::imread(path.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));
    labels.push_back(i);

    i++;
}

try {
    model->train(images, labels);
} catch (const std::length_error& e) {
    std::cerr << "Length error: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

I am absolutely certain that all the images load as expected.
The only output I get is `vector<T> too long`. It throws that exception even if the length of both vectors is 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: exact error msg, please. also, you seem to increase i with every image. if you had a folder per person, it should only change , when the folder changes, you want one distinct label per person.

Comment: @berak - `vector<T> too long` is the exact error message. i increase `i` with every image because i load one image per person.

Comment: 1 image per person won't be enough. use more like 20 for this. also, looking at the [src](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp#L910), it never throws a std::length error

Comment: try to catch a cv::Exception instead

Comment: @berak - yeah, i don't see it throwing it anywhere either, but that's what i get every time. i tried catching a cv::Exception, but there isn't one. the std::length_error exception gets thrown when it tries to allocate something. i don't even know why it's trying to allocate memory, but if i don't catch the exception, it breaks on a malloc in new.cpp.

Comment: in that case, rather check your link settings. any chance, you're mixing release/debug libs or using the wrong ones ? your code looks quite unsuspicious.

Comment: a few lines from your galleryFile would be helpful, too.

Comment: @berak - it seems the problem was in the libs. i'm working on an already established SDK, so i haven't even checked the opencv libs. thanks!